# FlutterObservatoryPublisher Error on iOS version of Flutter App

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error from my flutter debug console "[VERBOSE-2:FlutterObservatoryPublisher.mm(143)] Could not register as server for FlutterObservatoryPublisher. Check your network settings and relaunch the application."

I'm building a matchmaking app and I want to be able to notify users with a local push notification when a match is found if the app is minimized or screen is closed.  My issue is I can't get the iOS version of my app to run in background to continue listening to changes in the database.  My database is Firebase Realtime Database, and I need the app to stay awake while searching for a match.  I am using the package flutter_background_service to keep the match searching process running in background. I have been able to get the background service to work on Android, but can't on iOS.  In debug mode, the iOS version works fine in background but doesn't in profile or release mode.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you enabled background processing in xcode?

Comment: Yes, but I am still having the same issue.  Anything else I should be doing on top of enabling background processing?

Comment: Try uploading a release to test flight and check if it's working

Comment: I can't build the product archive because I get this error "Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'" from my SwiftFlutterBackgroundServicePlugin. Here's the part of the code that produces the error:

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
    private(set) lazy var tmpTask: BGAppRefreshTask? = nil

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I faced this issue and I'm enabling the background processing and background fetching

Comment: I pivoted to using FCM Messaging to send the notification to the user instead of local notification. The notifications trigger every time on iOS

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following

1. Enable background fetch and background processing
2. Add these in info.plist

```dart
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<!-- Background Processing -->
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>processing</string>
</array>

<!-- Task Schedulling -->
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
   <string>workmanager.background.task</string>
</array>

<!-- Background Fetching -->
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

3. In appdelegate.swift

```dart
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(/* Your Desired Interval for Background Tasks */)) 
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: I followed your recommended steps, but I still can't get the app to run in the background.  When a match is found, the iOS user still doesn't receive a local notification unless they are actively using the app.  I'm not using the workmanager flutter plugin.  I am using the flutter_background_service plugin.  It works on android, but not as expected on iOS.  Any other suggestions?